# Append a table with the result of a select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a SELECT query to return all of the records from my table `WHERE FieldCount = 3`.
I'd now like to append the result of this query to the same table with a new value of `FieldCount`.

How would you go about appending the results of a query to a table and altering the value of a field?

Answer (score 2):

WHERE and SELECT clause are independent of each other. You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (foo, bar, FieldCount)
SELECT foo, bar, 77 As FieldCount 
FROM myTable
WHERE FieldCount = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Query and base it off the query you just created off that table.

- Make sure that the new query is an **append query**
- Add all the fields to the query in design mode
- For the new "FieldCount" number, Just place whatever number you want them all to be in the field combobox.

Notice the number 3 is the value I chose to add to the table.

[image: Append Query]

[image: Results in Table]

Edit: Andre beat me to it, but his method is easier unless you prefer the GUI way of doing it.